# Basic JS Q after "validation" with JSLint

Tags: javascript

I just ran one script through [JSlint](http://www.jslint.com/) and received tons of errors - all related to the example below. Now I need to clear some basics, as I'm honestly pretty new to JS and don't know if those are "critical" Errors, Warnings or notices.

```
var whatEver = {
    foo:         null,
    fooArray:    [],
    // This tells me that the curly bracket was expected much earlier
    barArray:
    {
         whatever:    'somestring'
        ,keyTwo:      'anotherstring'
    },
    // Here I get told that I got "wrong" white spaces
    bar:         document.getElementById( 'someID' )
};
```

I know most of this is "basic" js stuff and so far everything's working fine. I just want to know if I'm making basic mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: try again but check these options 'Assume a browser' for the document element and 'Tolerate messy white space' for white spaces, as Jamund mention you have just one error semi-colon after document.getElementById( 'someID' ), regards

Comment: @nerdcoder Thanks for the note - I already found the option "messy white space" - I'll give "Assume a browser" a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some feedback:

1. It's not that normal to have a lot of whitespace after property names. Maybe it's a copy/paste problem.
2. Objects as shown by the {} are not arrays, FYI. SO you might not wants to call them arrays. You can make an array literal by using [], if that's what you want.
3. document.getElementById( 'someID' ); should NOT have a semi-colon at the end. That's your biggest mistake.
4. You sometimes use comma-before syntax and sometimes use comma-after. You could probably just stick with one. Personally, most of my JS is in node and comma-before is pretty normal there. Either works though. http://css-tricks.com/7741-commas-before/
5. I put this in my code example, but didn't mention it up here. Braces should always be on the line with the parent. This is because of automatic semi-colon insertion, which can screw you up if you put a return on the line before {}. See: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/. Thanks Michael for mentioning it below!

Here's what I'd go with. http://jsfiddle.net/n87Cn/ JSLINT doens't like it, but I think it's quite nice.

Comment: Additionally, (the first error reported), jslint expects opening `{` to be on the same line as its identifier, as in `barArray: {`, rather than on the following line. Crockford drives this point home again and again.

Comment: Sorry for the mess - I just quickly typed it off by hand, no copy/paste. It's just an example and not the actual code (has some hundred lines). The array _is_ and `array[]` and the `document.getElementById( 'someID' )` doesn't have a semicolon at the end. The problem jSLint seems to have with my code are opening curly brackets at a new line. He then associates them with some previous object. That's what I don't get. Anyway: +1 @Michael gave the answer. Thanks for that. Btw: What/Who is "Crockford"?

Comment: Crockford is Douglas Crockford. He wrote JavaScript: the good parts, JSLint, and I believe "discovered" JSON. http://javascript.crockford.com/ He also has some killer talks which you can watch here: http://yuiblog.com/crockford/. Oh FYI, you may want to check out JSHint. It's more community-driven and flexible than JSLint. http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. About JSHint: **MUCH** better (and also better looking). Thanks for the heads-up. Btw: a) Are there any potential problems, when I add `,`-commas at the beginning of a line (instead the end) and b) If I get the message "_mixed spaces and tabs_", could that make my script unstable or something?

Comment: Let's see. 1) Commas at the beginning are really nice at catching missing commas at the end. There's no real problem with it, but it's not the most common style on the client-side. 2) Mixed spaces and tabs is annoying, but causes no real problems. I recommend just choosing one though!